# How can I split a data table imported from Excel in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, compare

Good morning.

I successfully imported in Java an Excel spreadsheet with a table of data with this code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Readsheet {
   static XSSFRow row;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("codes.xlsx"));
      
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
      Iterator < Row >  rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();
      
      while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
         row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
         Iterator < Cell >  cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
         
         while ( cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
               case NUMERIC:
                  System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " \t\t ");
                  break;
               
               case STRING:
                  System.out.print(
                  cell.getStringCellValue() + " \t\t ");
                  break;
                   
               case BOOLEAN:
                   System.out.print(
                   cell.getBooleanCellValue() + " \t\t ");
                   break;
                   
               case ERROR:
                   System.out.print(
                   cell.getErrorCellValue() + " \t\t ");
                   break;
                   
               case _NONE:
                   System.out.print(
                   cell.getErrorCellValue() + " \t\t ");
                   break;
                   
               default:
                   break;
            }
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
      fis.close();
      workbook.close();
   }
}
```

First row contains the titles, and the others contain the information about each product.

I need to split this table in multiple arrays in order to compare them, how can I do it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/), for example...

Comment: Yes, I've used it to import the data, but how can I split them?

Comment: Can you show us how you are importing then (code)? What data structures do you use? From what you wrote, it seems better suited to create a class that represents a row and add them to a `Collection` or array.

Comment: Sure! I edited the question.

Comment: You can use a `List<List<String>>` or a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` and simply put the values there for each row... Even a `String[][]` might work. You are currently printing the values depending on their cell types, so you may want to create a cusom class that stores the values with the desired attribute types.